# Multiple Filters PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a project where I'm exporting data to an excel file using PHPExcel. Now there is no problem creating the excel file. But now my client wants to be able to have multiple filters on multiple columns. I know I can add a filter by using:

```
->setAutoFilterByColumnAndRow($column, $rownumber , $column, $rownumber)
```

So I tried adding more filters to different columns, but then only the last one that is created will be shown in the Excel file.

Example of what I generate:

```
Column A --  Column B -- Column C
Value 1 --   Value 2 --  Value 3
 ...     --   ...     --  ...
```

Is there any way to generate multiple filters so that i can sort my data accordingly to column A, B or C?! Any help would be appreaciated, since i'm stuck on this for a few days now.. .

I thank you for taking your time for reading this and possibly trying to help me out. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an entire document dedicated to working with autofilters (PHPExcel AutoFilter Reference developer documentation.doc) in the /Documentation folder of the distributions and available [online](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation%20AutoFilters) on the github wiki..... but you can only have one autofilter range on any individual worksheet, and that's an Excel restriction, not a PHPExcel restriction.

But you also specify the **range** of the dataset that you want filtering applied to, not a series of individual columns: that's the way Excel works

Sorting is not an option supported by PHPExcel because of the complexities involved in actually reordering all the data in every row of the worksheet.

Comment: So there is no way of implementing this?

Comment: If MS Excel doesn't allow you to have more than one autofilter region in a worksheet, then PHPExcel isn't going to either